# React native svg chart graphs

Tags: react-native, bar-chart, react-native-svg, react-native-svg-charts

```
import React from 'react'
import { BarChart, Grid } from 'react-native-svg-charts'
import { Defs, LinearGradient, Stop } from "react-native-svg";

class ColorBarExample extends React.PureComponent {

    render() {

        const data = [
            {
                value: 50,
            },
            {
                value: 10,
                svg: {
                    fill: 'rgba(134, 65, 244, 0.5)',
                },
            },
            {
                value: 40,
                svg: {
                    stroke: 'purple',
                    strokeWidth: 2,
                    fill: 'white',
                    strokeDasharray: [ 4, 2 ],
                },
            },
            {
                value: 95,
                svg: {
                    fill: 'url(#gradient)',
                },
            },
            {
                value: 85,
                svg: {
                    fill: 'green',
                },
            },
        ]

        const Gradient = () => (
            <Defs key={'gradient'}>
                <LinearGradient id={'gradient'} x1={'0'} y={'0%'} x2={'100%'} y2={'0%'}>
                    <Stop offset={'0%'} stopColor={'rgb(134, 65, 244)'}/>
                    <Stop offset={'100%'} stopColor={'rgb(66, 194, 244)'}/>
                </LinearGradient>
            </Defs>
        )

        return (
            <BarChart
                style={{ height: 200 }}
                data={data}
                gridMin={0}
                svg={{ fill: 'rgba(134, 65, 244, 0.8)' }}
                yAccessor={({ item }) => item.value}
                contentInset={{ top: 20, bottom: 20 }}
            >
                <Grid/>
                <Gradient/>
            </BarChart>
        )
    }

}

export default ColorBarExample
```

As this is giving me a simple gradient but i am need a gradient like this. How can i get it in this gradient .

[image]

Let me know how can i draw it like this image so that each gradient have some borderradius at the top and and have a custom gradient colors as per image and also can be of small width instead of long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give vertical gradient by this `x2={'0%'} y2={'100%'}` in `Gradient` function and for rounded corners you can try [this](https://github.com/JesperLekland/react-native-svg-charts/issues/48#issuecomment-417945514)

To change width of bar you may try `spacingInner` property.
To give gradient to all bars, we should manage svg fill property of data array.
[here](https://snack.expo.dev/@wmt_rn_asmeetarathod/barchartdemo) is the link of your barchart code demo. Please check if it helps.

Comment: Hi @Asmeeta this can be work only for You for one person how to run it for all as it is taking svg fill. Also how can i reduce with of it. Let me know if you have an idea with this code.

Comment: Hi @Rover, I've edited my answer, please check.

Comment: Thanks @Asmeeta Rathod this helps. But this round corners is not working as i want that it will work with the <lineargradient/>
  <Defs key={'gradient'+index}>
        <LinearGradient id={'gradient'+index} x1={'0'} y={'0%'} x2={'0%'} y2={'100%'}>
          <Stop offset={'0%'} stopColor={color[0]} />
          <Stop offset={'100%'} stopColor={color[1]} />
        </LinearGradient>
      </Defs>